# Alexa Node.js Skills Kit - Need to return callback data before handler is completed

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm attempting to build a simple Alexa skill to return data from an API using the [Node.js ASK] (https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx213D2XQIYH864/Announcing-the-Alexa-Skills-Kit-for-Node-js). I have put the http get within a handler, but Alexa completes the handler before the callback asynchronously returns the API data.

I have been searching for answers, and my thoughts are currently:

1. not use node.js
2. figure out a way to synchronously get the data
3. Something simple I am missing

Core of the code:

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handler);
  alexa.execute();
};

var handler = Alexa.CreateStateHandler(states.x, {
  'intent': function() {
    var options = {
      host: baseURL,
      path: pathURL
    };
    
    callback = function(response) {
      var str = "";
      response.on('data', function(piece) {
        str += piece;
      });
      
      response.on('end', function() {
        //does not get executed
        this.emit(':tell', str, "test");
      });
    }
    
    http.request(options, callback).end();
    
    //this does get executed if I leave this here
    this.emit(':tell'...);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a scope issue.
try ...

```
response.on('end',() => {
    this.emit(':tell', str, "test");
});
```